# Java Iterator for a parameterised type

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to write an itertor for a type of ArrayList, where Number is a class.

I can **almost** do it, but I get errors:

This is the class definition

```
public class History implements Iterable<ArrayList<Number>> {
```

This is the definition of the type I wish to iterate over:

```
private ArrayList<Number> spins = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

... and here are the iterator functions:

```
   @Override
    public Iterator<ArrayList<Number>> iterator() {
        Iterator<ArrayList<Number>> it = new Iterator<ArrayList<Number>>() {

            private int currentIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentIndex < gethistorySize() && spins.get(currentIndex) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public ArrayList<Number> next() {
                return spins.get(currentIndex++); // ** ERROR **
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }
```

I get an error at the lines marked ** ERROR **

The error I get is:

Multiple markers at this line
- The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayLisy
- Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Number to ArrayList

I am not quite sure what to return here.

Can anybody help?

Thx

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
- The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayLisy<Number>
Type mismatch: Cannot conver from Number to ArrayList<Number>

Comment: Could you add error message so people with same problem would be able to find your question and possible answers?

Comment: Done above, sorry - and, just to note, it is not a run time error, but a "screen error" so cannot complie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
        @Override
        public ArrayList<Number> next() {
            return spins.get(currentIndex++); // ** ERROR **
        }
```

To

```
        @Override
        public Number next() {
            return spins.get(currentIndex++); // ** ERROR **
        }
```

Return type is wrong hence the compile error.
When you call `next()` method, you want to iterate each Number object within An `ArrayList<Number>`.

Comment: Thansk - just for info - that removs the original error, but gives a (similar) error on the changed line

Comment: @Graham [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/simple-example-of-an-iterable-and-an-iterator-in-java) try some of this example

Comment: Many thanks all - changing the type to <Number> respolved this.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `spins.get(currentIndex++)` to return an `ArrayList<Number>`, the type of `spins` would have to be `List<ArrayList<Number>>`, not `ArrayList<Number>`.

If the type of `spins` is correct, perhaps what you need is to implement an `Iterator<Number>`, not an `Iterator<ArrayList<Number>>` (and `History` should implement `Iterable<Number>`).

Comment: Thnak you - I will try these suggestions